# How to parse a string to html in handlebars

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, handlebars.js

I am trying to parse a string to html in handlebars.

Example:
in `.js` file

```
let url = 'http://google.com';
let textref = `<a href=${url}>Click here</a>`
```

in `.hbs` file

```
{{textref}}
```

`Expected output :` `Click here` text holding the hyperlink 
`Actual output` :  `<a href=http://google.com>Click here</a>`

Actual output is the string instead of text reference holding the hyperlink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `{{textref}}` with `{{{textref}}}` in your code.

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", {{{.

[Ref](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping)

Answer (score 5):

Use the escape `{{{` syntax:

```
{{{textref}}}
```